# To make the bot react to the last the last message or react to a message with message ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make the bot react to the last message sent by a command, I've tried but except it gives me an error that `Message Argument must be a Message` In addition I've also tried to make the bot react to a message with a message id a user gives, Below is what I've tried to do

```
# (Most important) This should react on the last message with the  emoji (Not this message it self)
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def react(ctx):
    Channel=ctx.message.channel
    logs = client.logs_from(Channel, limit=1) #This is meant to check the last (1) message
    await client.add_reaction(logs, emoji="")
```

## And the other script

```
# (Least important) This should react to a message that has the message id you give
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def like(ctx,Message_id):
    message=Message_id
    await client.add_reaction(message, emoji="")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first example `logs_from` is a coroutine (needs to be awaited) that [returns a generator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) so you can do something like

```
async for msg in logs:
  await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji="")
```

For your second example, you are passing the first argument of your command in as the message but you're getting a string of the message id
You need to first turn that string into an integer and then find the message with that id

```
message= await client.get_message(ctx.message.channel, int(Message_id))
await client.add_reaction(message, emoji="")
```

*Note for the first example*
If you want to get the second to last message you can do something like

```
await logs.__anext__()
await client.add_reaction(await logs.__anext__(), emoji="")
```

Comment: It works but the problem with the first one is that it reacts to the message you send not the message the last message someone sent not the one you're sending

Comment: That could be a bit tricky since [LogsFromIterator](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/iterators.py) uses an [asynchronous generator function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) to do this but I've edited my answer with a solution